# How many region based UILocalNotifications are allowed for single app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Apple [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/region) says :

> Apps are limited in the total number of regions they may monitor at
>   any given time, and local notifications configured with a region value
>   count against that total.

But `total number` are not specified, how to know the limit of the total number of regions app can monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number is limited to 20 per app, according to Apple's [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) :

> Be judicious when specifying the set of regions to monitor. Regions
>   are a shared system resource, and the total number of regions
>   available systemwide is limited. For this reason, Core Location limits
>   to **20** the number of regions that may be simultaneously monitored by a
>   single app. To work around this limit, consider registering only those
>   regions in the user’s immediate vicinity.